# Layout switcher is not available

Tags: experience-editor, presentation

Probably some one knows why the Layout Switcher in the Experience Editor mode can be disabled and I can't manage the Shared Layout?

[image: Layout Switcher is not available]

---

I want to manage the shared layout for my branch template.

[image: Editing brunch template]

---

I guess the reason is pretty simple but I need help.

Comment: I hope this link will help you -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994161/sitecore-8-1-layout-switcher-disabled Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was simple. It happens when current site is resolves incorrect. When I set a correct site in sc_site parameter in the URL, I will be enabled the swither.